# Extjs Custom TriggerField implementation

Tags: asp.net, javascript, extjs

This is my first question here.

I hope I can contribute with answers too..

My need is to build an `Extjs` `TriggerField` implementation which open on trigger click a Panel with a custom loaded page inside...

example: When I click the trigger button I what to open a panel specifying an url as `/Views/Test/Blabla.aspx` and then storing the selection in the trigger field value.
I hope someone could help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is an example which pops up a Panel in your examples directory under examples/form/forum-search.html

It's based on a ComboBox (But it configures it to hide the trigger button)

BTW, probably a better idea to ask for help at http://extjs.com/forum/

Comment: I asked help but the only obtained answer was "There's a lot to study.."

Comment: Yes, sorry but your question is too open-ended for someone to give specific implementation advice. A lot of what you're asking for requires experience implementing UIs with Extjs. SO is not your personal consultant, here to do write whatever code you want.